# flink-streaming-java is not available in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to run Apache Flink but getting the error as dependency not available.
Is the module `flink-streaming-java` still available.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I have used 0.9.1 and few more versions, but none of them worked.

On checking further in flink-streaming-java https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/pom.xml

found -

```xml
<!-- disable fork reuse for the streaming project, because of
     incorrect declaration of tests -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The module `flink-streaming-java` has been renamed from `flink-streaming-core` just yesterday. I assume that the new dependency hasn't been uploaded/published yet to the snapshot repository. In order to circumvent the problem, you can install the latest Flink version to your local maven repository by `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`

Comment: on doing that The POM for org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java:jar:0.10-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: i will wait till tonight , may be with nightly push, streaming jars will be available in the repo

Answer (score 0):

[Flink Streaming Java » 0.10.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java/0.10.0)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please do not just dump code but explain your solution.